# Getting "source type is not polymorphic" when trying to use dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct A {};

struct B : A {};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B();

    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
}
```

gives:

> [cannot dynamic_cast 'a' (of type 'struct A*') to type 'struct B*' (source type is not polymorphic)](https://ideone.com/wxHBB3)

How can I make `A` polymorphic?  I want to safely cast it to B.

(One way is to add a dummy virtual function, but is there a better way?)

Comment: If you don't need virtual functions, why do you want polymorphic types? `static_cast` works just fine here.

Comment: Adding to R. Martinho comment... if you feel that you need to perform casts you might already be in the wrong track.

Comment: Virtual destructor for polymorphic type is not dummy - it saves you from UB if you decide to fix your memory leak by writing `delete a;`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I want it to return `0` if it isnt B.

Comment: @user1131467: That is why I said *might already be*... although in general casts tend to indicate flaws in the design.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec That's true but the compiler should really complain already at "A* a = new B();"

Comment: @all above: There are lots of reasons to have polymorphic types without virtual functions. In my case I have a class that returns an event object to a callback handler. This is subclassed depending on what the event is. Some events contain a message (info/warning/error), some events contain a % progress value, and so on. The base class contains a type value so that the handler knows which sub-class to dynamically cast the event to.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You need to make `A` polymorphic, which you can do by adding a `virtual` destructor or any virtual function:

```
struct A {
  virtual ~A() = default;
};
```

or, before C++11,

```
struct A {
  virtual ~A() {}
};
```

Note that a polymorphic type should have a virtual destructor anyway, if you intend to safely call delete on instances of a derived type via a pointer to the base.

Answer (score 17):

You need at least a `virtual` function - typically, if no others are suitable, the destructor:

```
struct A {
   virtual ~A() {}
};
```

Comment: I thought I don't need a destructor because the class has no member data. Turns out it needs one, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

As your compiler says, your type `A` is not polymorphic. You should add a `virtual` function to it. For instance, a `virtual` destructor could be a good choice:

```
struct A { virtual ~A() { } };
//         ^^^^^^^ This makes A a polymorphic type

struct B : A {};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B();

    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a); // Should work now
}
```

Comment: I thought I don't need a destructor because the class has no member data. Turns out it needs one, thanks!