# Convert by "dynamic_cast" between points to classes

Tags: c++, class, casting, compiler-errors, dynamic-cast

I tried to convert by "dynamic_cast" in the following way:

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape {
    //....
};

class Square: Shape {
    //....
};

class Circle: Shape {
    //....
};

int main() {
    Circle cr;
    Shape* sh = &cr; // ERROR1
    Square* psq = dynamic_cast<Square*>(sh); //ERROR2
    return 0;
}
```

And I get error messages:

> ERROR1: 'Shape' is an inaccessible base of 'Circle'
>
> ERROR2: cannot dynamic_cast 'sh' (of type 'class Shape*') to type 'class Square*' (source type is not polymorphic)

Can someone explain why I get these errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Comment: You are inheriting privately from class `shape`. You should make it `public`: `class Square : public Shape`...

Comment: @Raindrop7 But still I get `ERROR2`

Comment: @NickyC I agree that it's related to `ERROR1` , but what with `ERROR2` ?

Comment: It is related to code that you do not show us.

Comment: @NickyC That is all my code..

Comment: Then, it is literally what it say: The class is not polymorphic.

Comment: @NickyC And what is the meaning of that?

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114093/getting-source-type-is-not-polymorphic-when-trying-to-use-dynamic-cast

Comment: @NickyC Why I need from the beginning to make `Shape` as polymorphic? What is the problem now?

Comment: Because you are using it as a polymorphic class. The problem is you are using a non-polymorphic class as a polymorphic class, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @nickyc Where it's seen in my code that I using it as a polymorphic class?

Comment: You must make the class polymorphic in order to safely downcast it using `dynamic_cast`. It's a stupid rule in C++ that you must have at least one virtual function to make a class polymorphic. If you wanna get around of it, replace `dynamic_cast` by `static_cast`, although the latter does not  have "safety check"

Comment: `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @NickyC So, if I can use `dynamic_cast` just about polymorphic classes?

Comment: @texasbruce It's just in case of downcast or that any using in `dynamic_cast` demand it?

Comment: I am only referring to your case which is a downcast. To know more about dynamic_cast, refer to the documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: Because you are trying to cast a `Circle` to a `Square`, which will fail and return null pointer. Again, you can use `static_cast`, which is **not safe** and allow you to cast in this case and return non-null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is that you must inherit publicly from `Shape` To be able to call the Shape's constructor in the derived object construction.

The second error is because class `Shape` must be polymorphic which means at least there's a virtual method:

```
class Shape {
    public:
        virtual ~Shape(){}
    //....
};

class Square: public Shape {
    //....
};

class Circle: public Shape {
};

Circle cr;
Shape* sh = &cr; // ERROR1
Square* psq = dynamic_cast<Square*>(sh);
```

- Polymorphism requires pointer to base class and virtual functions and operator overloading.
- You could use `dynamic_cast` to cast a derived class to a non polymorphic base class. But you cannot `dynamic_cast` a non polymorphic base to a derived class.

Eg:

```
Circle* cr = new Circle;
Shape* shp = dynamic_cast<Shape*>(cr); // upcasting
```

The lines above works fine even if the base class `Shape` is not polymorphic.

Comment: Can you explain why in this case `psq=NULL`?

Comment: If `dynamic_cast` fails in casting it returns `nullptr`; It fails when the pointer to be cased has not the address of object to be cast to.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile! Edit it first as I recommended in my solution then.