# How can I access a child class member stored in a parent class?

Tags: c++, pointers, sparse-matrix

I was assigned to create a sparse matrix. In the process, I got into a problem. I realized I could not access a member of a child class that was stored in a parent class.

I 'googled' my problem and what I got was that there were some casting problems. I tried it out and did not work either.

Sample code:

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:                     // public for example purposes
    Node<T> *down, *right;

public:
    explicit Node(Node<T> *d, Node<T> *r) : down(d), right(r) {}
};

template <typename T>
class HNode : public Node<T>
{
private:
    unsigned idxValue;

public:
    HNode(unsigned iv) : idxValue(iv), Node<T>(nullptr, nullptr) {}
};

template <typename T>
class ENode : public Node<T>
{
public:                     // public for example purposes
    unsigned row;
    unsigned col;
    int value;

public:
    ENode(unsigned r, unsigned c, int v) : row(r), col(c), value(v), Node<T>(nullptr, nullptr)
    {}
};

int main(void)
{
    Node<int> *root;

    root = new Node<int>(nullptr, nullptr);

    root->right = new HNode<int>(0);
    root->down = new HNode<int>(0);
    root->right->down = new ENode<int>(0, 0, 10);


    std::cout << root->right->down->value << '\n';
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
error: no member named 'value' in 'Node<int>'
std::cout << root->right->down->value << '\n';
```

Comment: The "parent" doesn't know *anything* about the child (derived class). Why would you expect it to be able to access it's members? It could have a thousand derived classes with different members - how would it know (it doesn't)?

Comment: Don't use `new`, use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: The answer to Jesper's comment is Runtime Reflection, something C++ doesn't support.

Comment: @Miguel Yurivilca The static type of the variables root, right, down is Node<int>. * In the class specialization there is no data member value.

Comment: What you can do is have a virtual function in `Node` that returns a highly abstracted form of the value, a `std::string` for example` that can be supported by all possible children of `Node`. Then you can `std::cout << root->right->down->getvalue() << '\n';` Each child of `Node` will have to implement this function and perform the conversion of their specific value into the abstracted type.

Comment: Your question is a little strange, supposing without knowing how the tree was made few lines before why do you decide to get `root->right->down->value` ? Of course you can use a dynamic cast to check if `root->right->down` is a _ENode_ but that seems artificial. What is the _real_ goal, to print a (sub)Node ? in that case define a virtual method for that, probably _pure virtual_ on _Node_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`root` is a Node pointer. `root->right` is another Node pointer. `root->right->down` is--you guessed it--a Node pointer.

When you do `[...]->value`, you're dereferencing that Node pointer, which gives you a Node, and then trying to get the `value` member on it. But Node has no `value` member!

You *could* attempt to cast your Node pointer into an ENode pointer, using dynamic cast. Which would look like:

```
Node *n = root->right->down;
if(ENode *en = dynamic_cast<ENode*>(n)) {
    std::cout << en->value << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "That's not an ENode!" << std::endl;
}
```

But to do this, you'll need to make Node polymorphic (which you can see detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15114118/2602718)).

Also note that in production code, you should be checking to make sure `root`, `root->right` and `root->right->down` are all non-null before going ahead and dereferencing them.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation @scohe001.

Answer (score 1):

The root class `Node` only has pointers to other `Node`'s it does not know about what derived classes they might be.

It is "usually" best to have the correct interface in the base class to get results/values from the different kind of derived classes.

So for example if you have a base class animal:

```
class animal
{
    virtual int number_of_limbs() = 0;
}
```

Then the derived class pig:

```
class pig: public animal
{
   int number_of_limbs() override { return 3;}
}
```

By doing this the "interface" to the class is generic but each derived/specialisation can have it specific value.

In your case you probably just need a function called `virtual int get_value()` in your base class and then implement that in your `ENode` class...

(note all code above is pseudo code only)