# Trying to cast base class pointer to a interface that derived class object implements

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am experimenting a little bit with inheritance in C++ and I stepped on a case that I don't quite understand. When I try to compile the code I get:

> error: cannot ‘dynamic_cast’ ‘base’ (of type ‘class Base*’) to type
> ‘class SomeInterface*’ (source type is not polymorphic)

I assume that it is not a proper way of casting, because SomeInterface is not related to Base, but is there a way to make it work? Maybe there something I can add to the class to make static_cast possible? Or is it just a bad architecture and I should rearrange my code to not introduce cases like this one? I'd appreciate any comments or resources I could read to understand this behaviour and possibly learn how to make it work.

```
class Base
{
    
};

class SomeInterface
{
    
public:
    void call_me() { }
};

class Derived : public Base, public SomeInterface
{

};

void try_call_me(Base* base)
{
    // line below causes an error
    SomeInterface* some_interface_instance = dynamic_cast<SomeInterface*>(base);
    some_interface_instance->call_me();
}


int main()
{
    Derived derived_instance;
    Base* base_instance = &derived_instance;
    
    try_call_me(base_instance);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ’dynamic_cast` only works when the class has one or more virtual functions. That’s what the compiler means when it says that the class is “not polymorphic”.

Comment: Why would `try_call_me` expect a `Base*` if it really needs to be given a `SomeInterface`?

Comment: *"I assume that it is not a proper way of casting, because SomeInterface is not related to Base,"* -- how did you come to this assumption? The error message already told you that the problem is that `Base` is not polymorphic. Instead of jumping to unwarranted conclusions, why don't you ask [what does the compiler mean by "not polymorphic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114093/getting-source-type-is-not-polymorphic-when-trying-to-use-dynamic-cast) (or search for `[c++] not polymorphic`)?

Comment: In general it's a bad idea for the holder of a base class reference to have to know explicitly what type the reference references. `virtual` functions handle this problem for you. If `main` cannot `base_instance->call_me();`, you almost always have a design fault. If you cannot define a common interface for all of the derived classes, you should look at solutions other than inheritance.

Comment: *"Or is it just a bad architecture and I should rearrange my code to not introduce cases like this one?"* -- as some other comments indicated, it's more of an "And" than an "Or". There is something you could add to the class to make the cast work, *and* you should probably rearrange your code.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` to `Derived *`.   The result of that will be implicitly convertible to `SomeInterface *` because `Derived` inherits from `SomeInterface`.   Bear in mind `dynamic_cast` will give a null pointer if it fails.

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` requires (except for up-casts) that the base class type used in the argument is *polymorphic*.

A class in C++ is called *polymorphic* if it has at least one `virtual` function. So you need to add one to your `Base`, for example the destructor:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

Polymorphic classes store additional information that is required for `dynamic_cast` to work at runtime.

However, that is a costly operation to do. Reconsider why `try_call_me` is expecting a pointer to `Base` instead of `SomeInterface` if that is really what it needs.

If you keep it as it is, you also need to add error checking to the `dynamic_cast`. It will return a null pointer if `base` doesn't refer to an object whose most-derived object contain a `SomeInterface` base class subobject that could be side-casted to:

```
SomeInterface* some_interface_instance = dynamic_cast<SomeInterface*>(base);
if(!some_interface_instance) {
    // didn't pass a suitable pointer, error!
    // fail here, otherwise there will be undefined behavior!
} else {
    some_interface_instance->call_me();
}
```

(If you use references instead of pointers, `dynamic_cast` will throw an exception instead of producing a null pointer value.)

Comment: is really adding one virtual function enough to enable dynamic casting? when it comes to why function try_call_me does ask for interface directly - well, behind this example there is a library that I am working with. so actually base class is not really base. it inherits from a base class that library provied and the function try_call_me is also inside a library that only accepts type that is available within the library. I can't change singature, because it would require me to rewrite library.

Comment: @anonymcodo Yes, adding a `virtual` function is enough. Classes that have virtual functions (aka polymorphic classes) are implemented differently than "normal" classes, which enables the function of `dynamic_cast`. However, you must add it _in the base class_, which according to your description you can't.

Comment: @anonymcodo "_and the function try_call_me is also inside a library that only accepts type that is available within the library.  I can't change singature, because it would require me to rewrite library._": You can't change the body of the function either if it is in a library outside your control. So where are you trying to put `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: I have an access to the body, but the way various systems are connected doesn't allow me to mess with the signature, because it would trigger major refactor. I've checked what you proposed and actually adding virtual function makes it work. thanks for info! out of curiosity - let's say I can't use dynamic_cast (sometimes RTTI is disabled) - is there a way enable static_cast? with some operator override or other cpp shenanigans?

Comment: @anonymcodo To do it with `static_cast`, the function must _know_ that the argument points to a subobject of a `Derived`. There is no way to verify this. You would then first need to `static_cast` to `Derived*` and then to to `SomeInterface*`. If the pointer doesn't actually point to a `Derived` subobject, this will cause undefined behavior. The extra information that RTTI adds is required to verify this at runtime.

Comment: @anonymcodo Adding a `virtual` function is ABI-breaking in the same way that changing the function signature would be. I would recommend adding a new overload of the function which accepts `SomeInterface*` as argument and implement the branch where the `dynamic_cast` succeeds in there. Then you don't need any RTTI or polymorphic functions. You need to apply some tricks to make one of the overloads preferred though in case both would be viable.

Comment: @anonymcodo What is supposed to happen if the user doesn't actually pass something derived from `SomeInterface`? Your old function does not have this as a precondition, so adding it now as a precondition would be as breaking as changing the signature would be. Or do you have an alternative path in the function if the `dynamic_cast` fails?

Comment: (But maybe you only care about API, not ABI. In which case adding a virtual function is fine.)